# Its Set cookie for login to admin but now wants to change session

Tags: php

hear is my code below how to set session for frequently login to admin because now its not login frequently

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{

  $id=trim($_POST['id']);
  $pass=trim($_POST['password']);
  if($id!='' && $pass!='')
  {
    $pass=md5($pass);
    $sd=mysqli_query($db,"select * from news_users where user_login='$id' AND user_pass='$pass' AND user_status='1'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sd))
    {

      ?>
```

Comment: where you setting up session ? Share complete code.

Comment: sir its my code to login from Admin but problem when i try to login is taking long time (means i attempt many time for login) i need help why

Comment: Check for user_status in mysql db.  mysqli_num_rows($sd) This will return number of records.

Comment: sir user_status show 1 now what i do?

Comment: Try with this : select * from news_users where user_login='$id' AND user_pass='$pass' AND user_status=1 . Assuming user_status is a Boolean field

Comment: sir i did but issue is same no change

Comment: What do you mean with "login frequently"?

Answer (score 0):

You have put `mysqli_num_rows($sd)` in `if`. It will return boolean and won't give you the actual number which you want
So change this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($sd))
```

to this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($sd)>0)
```